# Using rigid body physics to set objects' initial positions

Tags: animation, physics

I have a problem where I used physics to position a bunch of meshes in Blender and when I try to set the current frame to 0 it resets the position of the meshes that have been positioned with the use of physics.

Here is the [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28020).

Here is what the positioning looks like (Frame 300):

[image]

Here is what the positioning looks like after I try to set to frame 0 (Frame 0):

[image]

Comment: Can you please upload your blend file?

Comment: Where would you like me to upload it to?

Comment: Many people use http://www.pasteall.org/ and I use https://drive.google.com.

Comment: Here you go http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28020 please try and figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, so just to make sure I understand correctly: you want the bunch of meshes to be all down in the box at frame 1?

Comment: Also, do you need them to be separate objects or can they all be joined into one object?

Comment: Yes I wan them to be all separate and down in the box at frame 0 rather than one, because I want to make a object fall into the box into the meshes

Comment: Ok, I think I have an answer, I just need to figure out exactly how to explain it.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots please?

Comment: Yes, although it seems I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: It looks like we'll have to wait until more of the Blender experts come back...I can't figure this one out yet.

Comment: Whoa! Awesome answer by Garrett! I had no idea how to do that. That's the benefit of having lots of Blender experts around! :)

Comment: Don't forget to select his answer as working for you by clicking the checkmark so he get's credit for solving your problem. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The objects' positions get reset because, by clicking on frame 0, you are "going back in time" to the beginning of the animation.

To use the rigid body physics to set the initial positions to be what they are at frame 300, here's one method:

1. Select all of the objects involved in the rigid body physics simulation
2. Bake to Keyframes (in 3D View window, hit <kbd>T</kbd>, then select `Physics` > `Bake to Keyframes`)
3. Still with all the objects selected, open the Graph Editor
4. All the keyframes should be selected already.  If not, hit <kbd>A</kbd>.
5. Move keyframes back 300 frames (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>).
6. Erase all keyframes (<kbd>Delete</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you so much!! Exactly what I needed! Cannot thank you enough, my hero :)

Comment: Thanks! In Blender 2.8 one clicks on Object menu then Rigid body > Bake to keyframes..

Answer (score 22):

### **Apply Visual Transform**

Another way to solve this problem without the need to bake is to use Apply Visual Transform like this:

1. Go to frame 300 and select all the mesh pieces
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> -> Visual Transform

   [image]

Applying Visual Transform will set the Location, Rotation and Scale of all the selected objects to what they are on frame 300.

With this method, you don't need to bake the simulation and you also don't loose the rigid body settings.

Credit for this answer goes to [sergof](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3383/599) here on StackExchange.

Comment: I tried this in Blender 2.8 and does nothing, while the bake to keyframes works

Comment: In 2.8 this still works. Just remember to _Remove_ the Rigid Body from the objects after you Apply Visual Transform.

Comment: This didn't work for me either, in v2.9. The `Rigid Body > Apply Transformation` answer in the [linked question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3383/599) DID, however