# Is there a way that I can apply my physics so I can export them as obj?

Tags: physics

I am trying to fill my container with rocks using physics. Is there a way that I can apply this? Similar in applying modifiers? Because I want to export this as OBJ for a prop.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8169/using-rigid-body-physics-to-set-objects-initial-positions/8190#8190

Answer (score 3):

Select your object(s), go into the *Object* menu > *Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes* and choose the keyframe you want to freeze in the pop-up panel you'll have:

[image]

Or as pointed out by Duarte, select all, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *(Apply) Visual Transform* and remove the *Rigid Body*.