# How to bake rigid body physics frame in blender render?

Tags: modeling, mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation, baking

I have a model with some objects above eache other and enable rigid body physics for them so the upper ones fall on the lower one. Now when I play the animation to a certain frame how can I put it as the default location/rotation of the mesh?

Comment: Duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3290/599

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select all your objects and hit *Bake to Keyframes*. Set the starting and ending frames to the frame you want them to stay at. Go to that frame, and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>. This will remove the unnecessary keyframe.

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: Btw I used it to drop several layers of a giant sandwich onto each other, looks pretty neat. Also I used it for a blanket inside a picknick basket.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, just click Apply Transformation while on the appropriate frame. You can then remove the rigid body constraint and the object will stay at that point.

Or, rather than removing the rigid body constraint, just change it from Active to Passive if you want other objects to be affected by it.