# How can I create Light Streaks in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, path

I'm trying to make a light paths like there:

[image]

To achieve this light threads (streaks) I used a particles emmiter with shining icospheres and motion blur shutter like [Andrew](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sparks/).

I got this result:

[image]

First of all I wish to get full path of the light: from rising to falling.
And the second I wish to see the half circle path, but not the angle like now.

Maybe I should use another way to achieve the reference?

Blender 2.75, Cycles

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41783/is-it-possible-to-simulate-a-long-exposure-shot-in-blender

Answer (score 40, accepted):

An alternative method  would be not to use particles, and do the light streaks with curves. It might a bit more tedious to set up, but will not require as much computing power from your machine as particles do.

Give the curve a slight bevel and, by animating the **Bevel Factor** start and  end  values, you can control how the curve is rendered through the screen . You also have control on the resolution, curvature, start and end points, and you can precisely determine the trajectory.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

To change the width at different parts of the curve you can change the radius of the control points:

[image]

Add an emissive material to it and some glow on the compositor and you can easily achieve something like this:

[image]

If you give the curve some extrusion and bevel and a wild texture

[image]

you can have a lot of fun:

[image]

Comment: In this case it's a great alternative, but actually light streaks don't have a homogeneous thickness, is there a way to control the thickness with this method?

Comment: You can use another curve to provide the Taper object, then narrow the ends or even animate them. I recently achieved this effect by mapping a blend texture to the curve.

Comment: @poor by editing the radius of the curve you can change the thickness on different parts of the curve. See edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

If it needs a texture that follows the shape, like in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247719/how-to-create-this-tornado-or-electric-shader-in-blender-please-help-me#247719), you can create a cylinder, give it a *Curve* modifier, give it a material that is a mix between *Emission* and *Transparent* node with a *Noise Texture* as factor. You can keep the *Texture Coordinate Generated* output as it will stretch the noise along the cylinder shape. To give your object some real bumps you can give it a *Displac*e modifier, in that case make sure that it has a topology that is dense enough.

[image]

[image]