# Single verts mesh not moving with tracks even after hooking to the track

Tags: mesh, vertices, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I watched a video made by *CG Matter*, and tried it yesterday, and it worked fine. Excellent, even.
so today, I tried it with other footage.

1. I added the verts, snapping set to vertex, to each track thing.
2. I selected 3 verts, clicked f and a triangle appeared.
3. I repeated the process for all the verts.
4. I hooked each vert to the selected object (the track which I stuck it to)
5. Clicked play
6. Tracks moving, but verts and its triangulated planes not moving

[A link to the .blend file and the footage in my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13aR3B6XjlkxjMSip0mWWntNLX1gW3rwl?usp=sharing)

Am I overlooking something small? I just started blender and know the basics, if there is something else, i'll just look it up on Google.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, something like this?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61757/track-object-and-draw-path-on-top-of-video/61772#61772

Comment: Use vertex groups