# Can you set a motion tracker as an empty?

Tags: tracking

I'm trying to make an object follow a path from a recording, and I'd like to do it with the motion tracker.
I'm not trying to solve camera motion, just the object. I've got a tracker in the motion tracker, but I can't figure out how to make it an empty in the 3d space.
(of course, it'll only move in two dimensions.)

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61757/track-object-and-draw-path-on-top-of-video

Comment: @brockmann, It does, thank you.