# How Do I Create a self drawing 2D Shape?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transparency, effects, grease-pencil

Major Noob Question here but *I want to create a 2d shape that seems to draw itself like in this video below*:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLNmtk67unY

I saw in KaptainKrisitan's videos and wanted to replicate in blender, but I don't have a clue how.

Comment: You could try using the build modifier.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple way to make a drawing... draw itself:

draw a curve as your handwritten shape, or use Grease Pencil to draw your word, and then convert the drawing to a curve. See here:

[image]

Then you have (at least) two ways:

1. Use a mesh to create the writing depth, through arrays (fit length) and other modifiers: curve follow, subsurf. Then animating the "fit length" array parameter you can make it draw itself...

Here's how:

[image]

2. Use another (curve) shape as bevel object for the first curve. Then animating the bevel "end factor" you can make it draw itself...

Like this:

[image]

This becomes a 3D writing because the bevel object is a 2D curve circle, but you can also get a 2D animated writing using a 1D curve as bevel object, like this:

[image]