# Create a self creating box like in this video

Tags: modifiers, video-sequence-editor, wireframe, grease-pencil

I'd like to create a *simple line box that draws itself that I can import in Blender's VSE.*

This can be done in after effects like in this video tutorial: **https://youtu.be/YLNmtk67unY**
[image]
What methods would be best to recreate this and could I use such methods to creat other simple self revealing shapes a simple well?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: A nearly identical question arised yesterday, and had at least an answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68590/how-do-i-create-a-self-drawing-2d-shape. Any shape built like that can be "imported in VSE" as scene, imho.

Comment: try searching for python turtle or you can try this <https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html>

Comment: cheers for the response, sorry for the late reply, ill have a look at the other question and see if it answer my question. I'll also have look at the python turtle (though i've had no interaction with the python console as of yet).