# Modifiers array and curve

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have curve and plane with modifiers array and curve. I can not get the exact plane guide on the curve, sharp verticles. Anyone help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of array and curve on a plane, you could use a "straight" simple curve as a bevel object of your main curve, as shown below:

[image]

[image]

to animate the "shape" to follow the "curve", with all straight angles, you could just animate the start/end bevel factors, es:

[image]

subdividing the "path" curve more, in particular near the corners, will give more control on how the tip/end of the shape will follow it.

Comment: But if I want after make animation in this array and mesh then i can't?

Comment: ? I didn't get exactly how you want to animate this shape, later. Of course you can animate all of both curves settings, or you could of course convert the resulting shape above, made of curves, to a mesh and then animate that somehow, but it could depend on what you need to do...

Comment: I mean snake animation for curve

Comment: since you had a curve even with the array/curve modifiers, how did you try to animate the "snake" before? the issue with the shape not following exactly the sharp corners could be a different one...? If yes, ask another question on that specific topic: it would be what this site requires, and you also would get much better answers or hints...

Comment: I make curve. I apply location. then i make plane and add modifiers array, curve in this plane. I clear location. In modifier curve i choose first curve, and animate array.

Comment: do you mean something like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68590/how-do-i-create-a-self-drawing-2d-shape ?

Comment: Yes, but I want the mesh to be guided exactly on the curve

Comment: I added an example above. But maybe adding another question asking how to animate that curve as you wish (maybe adding some reference would also help)

Comment: I have another problem for flexures curves, as in the picture above

Comment: Ok, i solved. I choose handles type as vector

Comment: I have last question in this problem. Did i can change Bevel factor is all OK, curve is animated, but i want change end of curve, that not to be as spicy. Is possible?

Comment: ...as spicy? what do you mean?

Comment: A curve can also get a flat surface without a second curve object, increase the extrude value. Similarly, the bevel, resolution and fill type work together to get a full or part tube result.