# Synchronize an object following a path and the appearance of the path

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints

Using a [Follow Path constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html) as well as Cegaton's answer [from this page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles), I am trying to make a path appear behind a car as it follows a path.

Unfortunately, the speed at which the car and the path animate is different (they have the same number of frames however)...

[image]

I'm not sure what exactly makes this, and I'm not sure I can afford the time to keyframe or start tweaking each object to perfection.

Is there a simple reason I am missing out?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example file where the curve object has keyframes set to animate the curve geometry end, change the Bevel Factor type to Spline and set the interpolation of the keyframes to linear.

[image]

[image]

The different Bevel Factor modes for start and end are:

## RESOLUTION:

Resolution Map the bevel factor to the number of subdivisions of a spline (U resolution).

## SEGMENTS

Segments, Map the bevel factor to the length of a segment and to the number of subdivisions of a segment.

## SPLINE

Spline, Map the bevel factor to the length of a spline.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried, and it helps in the beginning and in the end, but the middle isn't synchronized at all. Could you try on your end with the .blend file and see if your solution works? http://ge.tt/6tW6GRj2

Comment: Sorry about that, I replaced my answer with a much simpler solution

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your answer, or actually an omission, both your previous answer that you removed (linear extrapolation in graph editor) AND your current answer (change to spline) need to be used together, just changing to spline doesn't work.