# extrude and animate a polygon along path

Tags: extrude

[image: extrude along this path]

Hello I have to make an animation with this shape, but i cant find out any tutorial to explain me the method to achieve the result I'm looking for.
I would like to extrude and animate a square shaped polygon that follows the yellow arrow path so that it builds up the entire shape in red.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you would like to accomplish. Could you draw some sketches of the animation?

Comment: Use curves and animate the bevel's factor start and end:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles/34383#34383

Comment: hello cegaton , i tryed that but it not what i need i need the shape to build up with a square form polygon and follow the yellow arrows on my drawing. when i tryed to animate the curves they was all moving in the same time and i would like to have the logo building shape after shape if you see what i neam , for aexample 1 the I 2 the N 3 the N etc

Comment: make individual curves, one for each letter and animate those sequentially.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rygyD.gif

Comment: thank you cegaton for your help , anyway i  still cant achieve what i need with the  curve and bevel , indeed its very usefull to animate a scriptural writing  but i really need to keep the shape of the logo wich is square basicaly. i am very new to blender i must precise i may have not yet memorize all the functions , but i thought that it should have a way to build up this logo keeping it sharp ;

Comment: cegaton that worked thank you very much  !!