# How Do I Make A Trace Effect Similar to Tron: Legacy Light Cycle Scene

Tags: modeling, animation, wireframe

I am trying to make an effect similar to the effect in Tron: Legacy in the light cycle scene. I am aiming for the effect found [from 0:04 through 0:12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GBLtnxxtzQ) in the video I linked. I feel like using a wireframe would be good but I don't know where to go from there.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GBLtnxxtzQ

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Cegaton already answered a very similar question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles).

You'll find a lot of tutorials on Youtube about light streak effects, there are a lot of ways, it really depends on how it is supposed to look like and how sophisticated you want it to be... I guess in the Tron movie they use several combined effects so even if I knew it would be hard to sum it up in few words. One of the most basic way to make a light streak could be this one:

- Create a curve, create a second one that will be its *Taper Object* (its profile from its start to its end).

[image]

- In the *Properties* panel > *Data*, play with the parameters to give your curve its thickness and its profile. The taper allows you to make the streak slightly disappear at its end.

[image]

- Play with the *End* value (and also maybe its *Start* value) and give it some keyframes to animate.

[image]

- Now in the *Node Editor* > *Compositing* mode, give a blur effect or else to give the glow effect.

[image]