# Sword Trail, Motion trail, Light Path

Tags: animation, particles, light

I've been googling for this for hours, actually more than that i always come to look for an answer after few weeks but I always give up. Why not try to ask i guess.

All i'm looking for is effect like that

[image]

I've seen only people talk about it or having questions about it but no answers. Only one answer i found was "there's plenty ways to do it" but not exactly how to.

I couldn't figure out how to do it on my own.
I know game engines have quiet easy way to do this in particle system but i'd like to know how to do that in Blender. Not just one slash trail after hit but continuous.

Comment: I would script this, particles are most probably not the most efficient way. What are your sources on that assumption?

Comment: do you want exactly what you show? For light streaks you have various solutions I guess, you could try with bezier curve as explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles  you could also try array + curve