# How to create this (tornado or electric) shader in blender? please help me

Tags: shaders

How to create tornado or electric effect?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, is it supposed to be animated?

Comment: See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: i tried but im a intermediate please help me

Comment: there was a similar question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles/247850#247850 ... I've added my own solution that may answer to your question