# How to make a shooting star in Blender?

Tags: particles, workflow

I have been looking a way to make nice shooting star in blender.
Is it possible to achieve something like this one?

[image]

I already searched on youtube, blender stack and didn't find what I am looking for.

Comment: you could try either particles or this kind of solutions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles

Answer (score 1):

This is a meteor shower done with particle systems. There's more than one way to do it. With particles I was able to get something similar to your ref. The particle system is set up to emit from the vertices and only the normal velocity is influencing their trajectories. Make sure to check off the random order check box in the source parameters or else you won't get streaks of particles. In edit mode you can check what direction the vertex normals are pointing to. You will have to rotate the geometry that emits the particles so that the streaks make diagonals across the camera view. The geometries that emit the particles also have to be flat or else you will have particle streaks pointing in different directions. The loop tools add-on has a helpful command to flatten geometry. That way all the vertex normals will point to the same direction. Gravity is turned off in the scene properties. A texture is applied to the particle systems to control the size of the particles. An icosphere with a white emission material is picked to be the rendered object. More than one mesh is used to emit particles and the particle system seed as well as emission lifetime and end are different for the particle systems. This was done for getting more variation (some long streaks and some short).
[image: particle-sys-sets-meteors]

[image: meteor-shower]