# Trails Behind Projectiles

Tags: modifiers, particles, add-on, compositing-nodes

How would I add comic-like trails to projectiles, such as arrows? I have an example from YouTube, but the effect is done in another software.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4lmGGSsFYg

The effect occurs around 27 seconds, where an arrow is shot and there is a blue trail behind it.

Comment: Try this:http://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/346-tutorial-light-streaks-in-blender.html  It uses the Motion Trail Addon https://sites.google.com/site/bartiuscrouch/scripts/motion_trail.  Unfortunately I haven't done this myself, so I won't make an actual answer.   Please let me know how this works out!

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34377/how-can-i-create-light-streaks-in-cycles

Comment: another which might be related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33993/how-to-make-precisely-defined-trails-along-orbits-in-space/45077#45077

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a particle system inside a particle system.

Just add the particle system you want to appear on the object you use for the first system, tweak the time and that should do it.

Comment: This won't work without using the particle instance modifier