# Why will my rigid body objects not come to a rest after landing in a bowl?

Tags: mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am making this scene of a bowl of chips in a bowl and I am trying the use rigid body physics to place them in the bowl in a realistic fashion.

There are two ways I have been trying to achieve this:

1. Simulating all the chips falling at once.

When I try is this the chips fall down and collide with the bowl just fine but then will not stop jigging bouncing and catapulting out and and thru the bowl.

2. Dropping the rigid bodies in one at a time.

This seems the prevent the jigging and clipping issues but I can't find a way to switch the individual rigid body back to a normal mesh without the timeline resetting thus preventing me from simulating the rest.
(I suspected if the turn the physics off for each chip after they stopped moving would prevent the next chip violently reacting with it).

Any ideas on how to get the damn things into the bowl and then turn them back the normal meshes?

[image]

Mesh collision box deform base.

I looked at other tutorials but nothing helped, I just dont know what the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Here's the site for uploading your file: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and a related question about rigid bodies http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26401/how-to-bake-rigid-body-physics-frame-in-blender-render. If you are looking for simulating a real behaviour I would suggest to simulate all at once, or you'll not get the interaction between all the pieces.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is quite simple! you need to enable deactivation on the chip meshes.

[image]

If they don't settle down fast enough, raise the linear and angular velocities. I'd especially recommenced the angular velocity (amount of rotation).

How this option works is that when the rigid body gets still enough, it is deactivated and stops moving.

For you particular simulation, values around 2.6 seemed to work well.

Here is a working .blend

[image]

Comment: didn't work. they still end up leaving the bowl. probably should have mention that the meshes keep clipping into each other, maybe that had something to do with it?. did it work for you? can you show a picture of the successful result?

Comment: @amillionlittlepolygons Here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cznxc.gif

Comment: @amillionlittlepolygons Higher FPS: http://gfycat.com/UnhappyRealHind

Comment: they still clip into eachother which is just about the last thing i want. anything than can be done about than?

Comment: @amillionlittlepolygons You will need to increase the simulation quality in the properties panel then; however, I will note it is virtually impossible to get a perfectly clean simulation.