# Physics Simulation. How to set current frame to first frame?

Tags: animation, physics

I need to do a simulation of bottles stacked in a bin in blender, as shown here. After 114 frames, I get the result I want, but I want to define this state as frame 1, how do I set it?[image][image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to set initial state with rigid bodies?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/is-there-a-way-to-set-initial-state-with-rigid-bodies)

Comment: Yes, yes! Thanks bro！This solve my problem perfectly!