# How to capture particle simulation at a particular frame to be initial state (Particle Edit frame 1)

Tags: particles, hair, particle-edit-mode

I am trying to do copy a Hair simulation at a particular frame to be it's frame 1 start point, almost like doing a Particle Edit but with the effects of gravity and Collision objects (example a hat on a head of hair):

[image]

I am aware of some solutions for [Rigid Body](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/is-there-a-way-to-set-initial-state-with-rigid-bodies), but cannot find a similar solution for Particles.   I realize I could use negative frame simulation start, but don't see why I need to use up the file size for all these throw-away frames.

Example: [image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly but AFAIK editing a particle simulation is bugged and does not work. In consequence, you cannot run a sim, stop at frame 50, edit it, and continue the simulation - nor cut the first 49 frames. The only workaround I know is to convert the hair at frame 50 to a mesh to "freeze/bake" it, then use the HairNet add-on to re-create the particle system. The re-created "baked" frame 50 can be edited and will be the start of the new sim. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/191147/107598

Comment: @Blunder -- thanks I will investigate HairNet, as I want to use the hair simulation at frame 50 to be the initial hair positions at Frame 1.   Quite doable in 3dsMax.